# How much weight will two 2x12 nailed together that are 18ft long hold?

Tags: wood, framing, ceiling

I am sitting in my living room looking looking at my ceiling wondering if the beam is strong enough to support the roof and ceiling after taking out a wall parallel and perpendicular to the beam.

Comment: How about a drawing/picture of where this wall is/was. Also, how can a wall be both parallel and perpendicular at the same time? Was there a corner involved somewhere?

Comment: If either wall or both are supporting the beam, then there is a good chance of failure, something goes boom on top of your head, if they are removed.  Supporting means the beam is resting/sitting on the wall/s at least at one point.  Removing of the wall/s can be done if over seen by an engineer.

Comment: Even if someone answers your actual question with a weight load, how does that help? Unless you know what your ceiling weighs, along with anything that may be found upon it, you're no better off than you are now. I suggest a heavy revision to ask a question that actually benefits you and provide enough information for us to answer properly.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the species and grade, each 2x12 will support about 120 lbs. per linear foot (plf) or both will support 120 plf x 2 = 240 plf.

If it’s a single load (point load) then it’s about 2200 lbs. at the center of the span, or for 2, it’s 2200 x 2 = 4400 lbs. depending on the species and grade.

Remember, 2x12’s and larger need to be blocked, or held in place with a
metal hanger.

Comment: I'll point out that there is a lot more to this than simply the carrying capacity of the boards.  Generally you will want, and your AHJ may require, an engineer or architect's stamp on your plans when making structural changes to your building.